# Finding a Tag With Multiple Elements in BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, tags, beautifulsoup

How would I find a tag like this:

```
<us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
```

and only find those with us-applicant sequence="001" (so not us-applicant sequence="002") using BS4? I am familiar with finding tags that look more like:

```
<applicant>APPLICANTNAME</applicant>
```

I am looking for something that would take this:

```
 <us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
  <some sub-tag>Data1</some sub-tag>
 <us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
  <some sub-tag>Data2</some sub-tag>
 <us-applicant sequence="002" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
  <some sub-tag>Data3</some sub-tag>
```

and when a I write a `vars = soup.findall(SOMETHING)
for var in vars:
 data = vars.find_all('some sub-tag')
 return(data.text)`

would only return Data1 and Data2, not Data3

Answer (score 0):

Blanks are disallowed in tags; I have therefore changed tags like `<some sub-tag>`, replacing blanks with hyphens.

The `soup.findAll` finds a list of the elements in the HTML with the tag 'us-applicant' and 'sequence' '002'. Since there's only one we choose the 0th element of this list. Now we ask this element for its element with the tag 'some-sub-tag'. Finally we display the `text` property of that element.

```
>>> HTML = '''
... <us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
...   <some-sub-tag>Data1</some-sub-tag>
...    <us-applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
...      <some-sub-tag>Data1</some-sub-tag>
...       <us-applicant sequence="002" app-type="applicant" designation="us-only">
...         <some-sub-tag>Data1</some-sub-tag>
...         '''
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> one_applicant = soup.findAll('us-applicant', attrs={'sequence': '002'})[0]
>>> one_applicant 
<us-applicant app-type="applicant" designation="us-only" sequence="002">
<some-sub-tag>Data1</some-sub-tag>
</us-applicant>
>>> sub_tag = one_applicant.find('some-sub-tag')
>>> sub_tag
<some-sub-tag>Data1</some-sub-tag>
>>> sub_tag.text
'Data1'
```

Comment: I forgot to edit my "Data" to be Data1, Data2, Data3. Does this answer still hold if the question is edited as above?

Comment: Yes. It's the *structure* of the elements that matters not the texts that they contain, unless you specifically mention the texts in the searches. You should try it. If it works then you should mark the answer accepted.